# LabelEncoder() returning different values for the same input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I used `LabelEncoder()` for transforming categorical data to numerical data. I have a dataset looks like this:

```
['x','s','n','t','p','f','c','n','k','e','e','s','s','w','w','p','w','o','p','k','s','u','p']
['x','s','y','t','a','f','c','b','k','e','c','s','s','w','w','p','w','o','p','n','n','g','e']
['b','s','w','t','l','f','c','b','n','e','c','s','s','w','w','p','w','o','p','n','n','m','e']
...
```

And I use `labelEncoder()` to do the transform. The code is below.

```
for m in M:
  le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
  le_fitted = le.fit(m)
  le.classes_
  encoding = list(le.transform(m))
```

And here is my result:

```
[11, 7, 4, 8, 6, 2, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 7, 7, 10, 10, 6, 10, 5, 6, 3, 7, 9]

[13, 10, 14, 11, 0, 4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 2, 10, 10, 12, 12, 9, 12, 8, 9, 7, 7, 5]

[0, 9, 11, 10, 4, 3, 1, 0, 6, 2, 1, 9, 9, 11, 11, 8, 11, 7, 8, 6, 6, 5]
```

My question is. why the same character got different numerical value? For example, the first value of both first list and second list is `'x'`, but I got different numerical: `11` and `13`. Why such things happened? When I inverse transform these values, I can get same result. i am not is there any problem with these result? would it affect my later operation such as using Naive Bayes classifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating and fitting a new `LabelEncoder` for each `m` in your loop. Instead you want to fit the encoder once, and then use that to transform each list.

You can do this by first getting all possible values to encode by taking the set union of all your lists.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from functools import reduce

# map each list in M to a set and then reduce using the set union (|)
all_M = list(reduce(lambda u, v: u | v, map(set, M)))
print all_M
#['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'f', 'k', 'm', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'p', 's', 'u', 't', 'w', 'y', 'x']
```

Next create an encoder and call `fit()` on `all_M`. Then use this fitted encoder on your lists:

```
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(all_M)

for m in M:
    encoding = list(le.transform(m))
    print encoding
#[16, 12, 9, 13, 11, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 3, 12, 12, 15, 15, 11, 15, 10, 11, 6, 12, 14, 11]
#[16, 12, 17, 13, 0, 4, 2, 1, 6, 3, 2, 12, 12, 15, 15, 11, 15, 10, 11, 9, 9, 5, 3]
#[1, 12, 15, 13, 7, 4, 2, 1, 9, 3, 2, 12, 12, 15, 15, 11, 15, 10, 11, 9, 9, 8, 3]
```

In general with any preprocessing step, you only want to call `fit()` once (typically on your training data). Subsequent data (including testing data) would then use the same fitted object for the `transform()` step.